# Java find a file on a drive that is unkown?

Tags: java, windows, search, operating-system, filereader

I have a file on an SD card that is a .txt file that my GUI needs to read the problem is that the GUI will be used on different computers and both on mac and windows OS. the .txt file is rather unique so wont be found on any other drive.

is there a way to scan every drive except C drive(to speed things up as i know it wont be there) to find the file so i can load it into my file reader?

thanks for any help?

Comment: Are u using it for only Windows based OS? or some in Linux where the SD is mounted

Comment: Please explain what task you're trying to accomplish. Even if you find a mechanism to do this, it'll be unusably slow.

Comment: Can that file be copied anywhere by the user? It'll be very slow to search the whole drive for it, so can you add a restriction or instructions for where that file should be located?

Comment: it will need to load the .txt data collected into a 2d array once so the GUI and play with the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java.io.File.listRoots()` to see the available drives.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive call through the entire file system: You can use the following methods of java.io.File:

```
listRoots()  : list the root files (In Windows it's the drives, on Mac OS X and linux it's '/').

listFiles()  : list the enclosing files of a directory
```

To recursively search for file check the following link

[Search directories recursively for file in java](http://www.mkyong.com/java/search-directories-recursively-for-file-in-java/)

Comment: thanks for the link, yes i am using mac os x and windows 7/8 i think the best thing for me to is a recursive search for the file name and get the file path to the file and make the file path into a string to work with my GUI. cheers guys. will play about to get that working now